# Renaming a datafile with a name stored in an object

Tags: r, rename, file-rename

I have datafile named `dat1` I want to rename it to `dat2` which I have stored in the object `filename`.

```
dat1 <- c(1:5)
filename <- paste("dat2")
```

If I use,

```
filename <- dat1
```

Then the `dat1` is renamed to `filename` and not to `dat2`.

So how do I rename `dat1` with the name stored in the object `filename` i.e. without mentioning `dat2`?

I tried using `file.rename` and `mv` but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `assign`

```
assign(filename, dat1)
dat2
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

and now `rm` the dat1

```
rm(dat1)
```

---

Or another option is `mv` from `gdata`

```
library(gdata)
mv(from = 'dat1', to = filename)
dat2
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

dat1
```

> Error: object 'dat1' not found

---

`file.rename` is used to rename a file name and not the objects in the global environment